# Switch connected to router. How to deal with port forwarding?

Tags: networking, router, switch

I have a dsl router which a 8 port switch is connected to it. If I connect computers to the switch how would I manage port forwarding in this setup? is it possible? would it be recommended in a production setting?

Comment: what do you expect to do with port forwarding? seems you are looking for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean "port forwarding" as in allow access from external (e.g. internet) to a certain port on a certain machine it should be no problem at all.
The switch connects the devices physically.

If your router also handles DHCP, you should be able to "see" the machines in your router's overview of network devices. Depeding on your router you should be able to to port forwarding from there.

What do you mean with "production"? As always, if you need to ask for "production", the answer is no ;-)